# TS2322: Type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'undefined' happen

Tags: typescript

i try to output a new object by mapping the keys of the input object from camel case to snake case.

TypeScript 4.6.0 has tail recursion elimination on conditional types

the transform seems ok

```
type CamelToSnake<T extends string, P extends string = ''> = string extends T
  ? string
  : T extends `${infer C0}${infer R}`
  ? CamelToSnake<R, `${P}${C0 extends Lowercase<C0> ? '' : '_'}${Lowercase<C0>}`>
  : P

type CamelKeysToSnake<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as CamelToSnake<Extract<K, string>>]: T[K]
}


type TInput = {
  defaultVisible: boolean
  defaultSize: number
}


type TOutput = CamelKeysToSnake<TInput>


function toSnakeCase(str: string) {
    var temp = str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function (match) { 
        return "_" + match.toLowerCase();
    });
    if(temp.slice(0,1) === '_'){
        temp = temp.slice(1);
    }
    return temp;
};

function test(input: Partial<TInput>){
  const output: Partial<TOutput>={}

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(input)) {
    const snakeKey = toSnakeCase(key) as keyof TOutput
    if (value !== undefined) output[snakeKey] = value
  }
}
```

but in the code line

```
if (value !== undefined) output[snakeKey] = value
```

unexpect error occurs

```
Type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.(2322)
```

why it happen? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

** Work around only **

I think it happens because the property `snakeKey` has an undefined type associated to it.

I don't know how to fix the property type, but you could work around the problem by using:

```
if (value !== undefined) Object.defineProperty(output, snakeKey, { value })
```

Comment: thanks Ben; i really want to know why the 'undefined' type happen; and now i just fix it by  change the type to unknown " (output[snakeKey] as unkown) = value"